# SQLAlchemy join - return all columns of one table

Tags: python, select, join, sqlalchemy

I am currently joining two tables returning rows where a column is in a list:

```
a = Table('a', server_metadata, autoload=True)
b = Table('b', server_metadata, autoload=True)

tickers = ['1', '2']
res = b.join(a).select().where(asset.c.code.in_(tickers)).execute()
```

This returns the correct rows and all the columns from both `a` and `b`.  How can I only return all the columns of table `b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`select`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select) corresponds to the `SELECT ...` part of the SQL query, and defaults to `*`; to limit it to `b.*`, you can give it a list containing the table `b`; with this construct however you need to wrap the `FROM` part into [`select_from`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/tutorial.html#using-joins) or otherwise SQLAlchemy will generate a subquery fragment. Thus:

```
res = select([b]).select_from(b.join(a).\
    where(asset.c.code.in_(tickers))).execute()
```